# Click on button in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to click on the `list` but they will give me `time out error` these is the page link https://www.s-ge.com/de/members-map

[image]

This is code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep


PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
url='https://www.s-ge.com/de/members-map'
driver =webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(url)


WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#m-view-tabs__button is-activ"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Clicking on `accept cookie`s is **optional**, it's not **required**.
2. You should launch the browser in full screen so that **Selenium** can have the list button in its `view port`.
3. If you observe even when you try to click **manually** on the `list button`, you are `scrolling` a little bit and then performing a `click`. You should `automate` that `scrolling` part as well.
4. Surprised to see that none of the answer are using `CSS_SELECTOR`.

**Code:**

```
driver_path = r'C:\\Users\\***\\***\\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)

driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://www.s-ge.com/de/members-map")


list_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-target-tab='list']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", list_button)
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: `arguments[0].click()` what is meaning

Comment: we can also written the last line  as -`list_button=list_button.click()`  is it working? instead of `arguments[0].click()`

Comment: `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", list_button)` this means that `list_button` is a `arguments[0]` in the `execute_script`, however `list_button=list_button.click()` would not work since it is required asyn JS click.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to use this XPath locator instead?

`//button[contains(@data-target-tab, 'list')]`

Either the locator is not correct, or the element is not clickable.
In case the element is not clickable, try to use js click.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@data-target-tab, 'list')]")
def js_click(self, element):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with xpath

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='m-view-tabs__button is-active']").click()`